# how to show alert when values is null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uialertview

I want to show alert when values is null i have titleCategory if it has value null then it should show alert

```
NSString*test=titleCategory;
if ([titleCategory isEqualToString:nil]) 
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Select Category " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else
{
    FirstViewController*targetController=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Change `if ([titleCategory isEqualToString:nil])` to `if([titleCategory length] == 0)`

Comment: iNoob thanks it worked what if i have there values i want that any of them is lenght o then show alert

Comment: Where are you setting the `titleCategory` variable?

Comment: you can just do `if (!titleCategory)`

Comment: @user1567956, i'm not quite getting what you mean sorry, you mean you've 3 `NSString` and show an alert when one of them has length 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(test == nil)
{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Test is null" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: i am using the above added code chekc that titleCategory in nslog show null

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if (!(titleCategory.length > 0) || titleCategory == nil ) 
{
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Select Category " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}
else 
{
   FirstViewController*targetController=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
   [targetController release]; // if not ARC 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code:

```
if([titleCategory.text isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Select 
    Category " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
  }
  else{
     FirstViewController*targetController=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetController animated:YES];
     [targetController release]; // if not ARC 
  }
```